# ImGui OpenGL Game Engine

Tags: c++, imgui

Hello I'm creating my first Game Engine with C++ and OpenGL, along with ImGui for the editor interface. I have a simple question, I created a window that covers the whole screen using:

```
ImGuiWindowFlags flags = ImGuiWindowFlags_NoResize | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoCollapse;
ImGui::Begin("ImGUI window", NULL, flags);
ImGui::End();
```

I also have docking enabled, I want to create a bunch of smaller windows (like tab windows) to be dockable inside of that main window. I tried doing that by using the BeginChild function but, while it created a child window it wasn't moveable in any way. I also tried creating another window but, when it's docked on the main window it goes fullscreen. Does anybody have any idea how I can achieve a bunch of child windows that are dockable and can be moved around?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out I can solve this by making the whole screen dockable:

```
// make the whole screen dockable
ImGui::DockSpaceOverViewport(ImGui::GetMainViewport(), ImGuiDockNodeFlags_PassthruCentralNode);
```

and then adding the windows.